# Como implementar um algoritmo de regressão linear em python?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Estou executando um trabalho na faculdade e gostaria de implementar uma função que calcula uma `regressão linear`. Dados os pontos e o número de expoentes desejados, quero como retorno os coeficientes da equação. Por exemplo, dados os pontos abaixo, e informando que quero apenas um expoente, gostaria que me retornasse os coeficientes `a` e `b` da equação de 1º grau.

```
>>> x = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.4]
>>> y = [1.4, 2.1, 3.5, 6.7]
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy.stats.linregress) da Lib Scipy.

```
from scipy import stats
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)#método de regressão
print slope
print intercept
print r_value
print p_value
print std_err
```

Comment: Lucas, eu gostaria de implementar um método e não usar um pronto. Eu já conhecia esse método mencionado, mas gostaria de implementar algum algoritmo de regressão linear.